# Asyn process stopped when object is disposed in API

Tags: c#, api, asynchronous, interface

While i call the web api, asyn method start process. After completed API process then asyn process also stopped. Here is my sample code snippet. Please give any solution for this.

```
    private readonly ITestService testservice;

    public TestController(ITestService test)
    {
      this.testservice=test;
    }

    [Route("Sample/SaveMyData")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult SaveMyData(MyInfo info)
    {
        MyInfo  inf = new MyInfo ();
        inf = testservice.SaveMyInformation(info);
        SendMailProcess(inf)
        return Ok<MyInfo>(inf);
    }

   private async Task<bool> SendMailProcess(MyInfo emailInfo)
    {
       await Task.Run(()=> this.testservice.SendMail(emailInfo));
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Eraiarasu, you are creating a separate Thread in your SendMailProcess and thats why your API call completes before the SendMailProcess completes.

Also, If you are trying to create async methods then please try to put await on SendMailProcess method invocation in SaveMyData as well. Also make SaveMyData as async too. Note that, you have SendAsync method in smtp api in .NET. So you don't have to use Task.Run as you did in SendMailProcess

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If i want to update something in data base, how can i use async in web api?

Comment: You have async counterparts for all the DB access methods. E.x, ExecuteNonQueryAsync could be used to execute an UPDATE.